# In iTerm how can I close a shell session when the running command finishes?

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm

I open some iTerm2 sessions via [`ttab`](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab). I start these session for textual UI commands like `top` or commands which might run for a long time like `cp -r <large-dir> <backup-location>`.

After the command has finshed the iTerm session stays open with the (bash) shell prompt. I have to close it manually via Ctrl-D.

How can I tell iTerm to close the session automatically when the shell is back at its prompt?

---

I tried using a special profile for this (because `ttab` can open the session in a specified iTerm profile), but I couldn't find a setting which closes the session when the shell is waiting at its prompt.

Comment: How much monitoring of the command's output do you need?

Comment: What about “&& exit” at the end of command?

Comment: @mmmmmm Nothing. Just want to run it.  The command might be long running like cp or an outputless “TUI” (like top).

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I tried “&& exit”, but ttab translates this into “\&\& exit”.

Comment: run it in the background `nohup <cmd> &`

Comment: @mmmmmm Well then I cannot interact with it. :-( The command can be e.g `top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is mentioned in the [example section of `ttab's` man page](https://github.com/mklement0/ttab/blob/master/doc/ttab.md#examples). Use `exec` as first argument to `ttab`. E.g.

```
ttab exec cp -r <large-dir> <backup-location>
```

or

```
ttab exec top
```